# Chatting System Architecture: Where to decrypt the messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, chat

I am designing an anonymous chat website that utilizes encryption. Should I decrypt the messages client-side or decrypt the messages server-side? Which method is more secure? I am using Node.js + Socket.io to develop the chatting system.

For example:

User A encrypts message, sends encrypted message to server, which sends encrypted message to User B which decrypts the message (client-side decryption)

or

User B encrypts message, sends encrypted message to server, which decrypts message and sends the decrypted message to User B (server-side decryption)

Comment: How can the users of the system trust that you aren't accessing the messages? Client side decryption gives the user peace-of-mind, doesn't it?

Comment: Secure in what aspect?  If the server decrypts the message, then the message is in the plain on the trip to the destination.  If the server does not decrypt it, then that means the destination has to be aware of how the source encrpted it, which is also a potential issue, if one client knows how another client encrypts.  A middle ground could be a contract by which the source encrypts the message with one key, the server decrypts it and re-encrypts it with another key, that only the destination knows how to decrypt.  But that's all theory without knowledge of where the security concern lies.

Comment: @Taplar The security requirement is that the system is EE2E (end-to-end encryption)

Comment: Then the source needs to encrypt it, and the destination decrypts it

Comment: If you encrypt the incoming message on the server side, and then decrypt it before you are sending it to the client, it will only be encrypted a very short time on your server, and you can remove it since it doesn't add any security. For it to be end-to-end encrypted the encryption and decryption must happen on the client side.

Comment: "_that means the destination has to be aware of how the source encrpted it, which is also a potential issue_" That is not an issue! That's how encrypted communication works. You would use asymmetric private-key encryption, meaning that the receiver can decrypt the message without knowing the key it was encrypted with.

Comment: And something that has been said over and over and over again: [Don't roll your own crypto](https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/wnx8nq/why-you-dont-roll-your-own-crypto)

Comment: @jmb The safest way is to just send a random string. Then it cannot be decrypted by the enemy or the recipient. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Decrypt the messages client-side.**

You mentioned in the comments that end-to-end encryption is a requirement. That means it **must be** impossible for the server to decrypt the messages.

Quoting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_encryption:

> End-to-end encryption (E2EE) is a system of communication where **only the communicating users** can read the messages.
>   [...]
>   In an E2EE system, encryption keys must **only** be known to the communicating parties.